# I am facing this error while i was trying to create my views in django i was trying to create a view called home_page

Tags: django, django-views

I am using django 5.0 I added the httprequest in my views.py and returned it but it is giving the following errors i have my **init**.py file and my server was running perfectly before this[[[[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf5MM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIsvy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQT0k.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A345.png)]

i was expecting for the page to return the http request

Comment: Hi. Don't post the code as images. Just post the code as ````code ````.

Answer (score 0):

As it shows in the picture you sent, you didn't create urls.py in your "leads" application. In urls.py you have to write urlpattern for your home_page function. This is an example code for urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('home_page/', views.home_page, name='home_page'),
]
```

Finally, you should add this urlpattern to the urls.py in "edgecrm" folder
It should look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('leads.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```